# What is a good benchmark to standardise computation speed (filter out machine speed)?

Tags: r, performance, computation

I have written a function in `R` that calculates a large array of values for an input argument.  (The specifics of the function is not important for the purposes of this question.)  I want to measure and report the computation speed of this function in some (roughly) objective way that does not hinge on the machine speed.  Since the speed of computers increases regularly, I am mindful of the fact that computation speed on my machine will differ from other machines both now and in the future.  I would like to report the computation speed in some standardised way that "filters out" the effect of the machine speed.

To remove the effect of the machine speed (as best I can) I propose to calculate the speed of my function, and compare this to the speed of some "benchmark function", done on the same machine.  I can then report the speed of my function as a multiple of the time taken to perform the benchmark function, and this should give me a (roughly) standardised measure of the computational cost of my function.  I already know that I can use the `system.time` function  in `R` to calculate the speed of functions, so now all I need to do is to pick an appropriate benchmark function for my comparison.

My background is in maths/stats, not computer science, so I'm a bit of a novice at this.  I'm sure it is something that is well-known, just not to me.

**Questions:** Does the method I have proposed make sense?  Is this method used generally in computer science, and if so, does it have a name I can look up?  Assuming the method makes sense, what is a good "benchmark function" to use for comparison?

Comment: I am no computer scientist, but I think that this is impossible. I have never seen "benchmarks" like your proposed idea. Even if you chose some "benchmark function", R internals are constantly evolving and multiple improvements are implemented. There are many factors that impact performance, and I think you will not be able to fix them.

Comment: I suppose that is why I am asking the question - I am looking for a benchmark function where the performance is (at least roughly) fixed relative to machine speed.  That is, I want a benchmark function that is **not** subject to efficiency improvement over time.  Maybe the answer is that there is no such thing, but I'd at least like to check with the experts first!